# Developing apps for Symbian OS v9.1, UIQ 3.0

Tags: symbian

I'm very new to Symbian application development. I'm googling some beginner tutorials about Symbian development. As there are many versions and many phone vendors, I like to ask you guys who are already have experiments in Symbian development..

My target is to develop small apps for sony ericsson w960i phone that uses Symbian OS v9.1, UIQ 3.0.

The goal of application is to save all incoming/outgoing calls/messages as a backup somewhere (txt file or isolated storage) inside the app.

For example: If I call to someone, my app should receive the events of number/contact name so I can save it to somewhere else.

Can someone help me to suggest to achieve this?

Can I use Nokia Qt to develop apps for  "sony ericsson w960i"? If not, which SDK should I use it for my app?

Can Nokia Qt be used to access call triggers/messages? I read that Qt can't access the internal OS stuffs but not sure whether accessing calls/message can be considered as internal OS stuffs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure about UIQ? This is even more dead than Symbian.
[Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIQ#List_of_UIQ_3.x_Phones_and_its_Version)

BTW, you can also use Symbian code in Qt application.

Comment: Yes. I have checked the specification for that phone.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main issue here is that neither Sony Ericsson nor UIQ don't even exist anymore.

Sony swallowed the first and the second went bankrupt after Nokia acquired Symbian itself.

So, whatever you end up doing won't be officially supported.

You can still develop applications for the w960i using JavaME but that doesn't have a telephony API so it won't help you with the kind of application you described.

Qt is not available at all on the w960i.

In order to develop applications using Symbian OS C++, you need the UIQ3 SDK. Since you can't download it from any official source anymore, you will have to google for places online where other people have uploaded it. Hopefully, you can find one with a legitimate untouched SDK.

The documentation in the SDK will help you create the UIQ-specific GUI for your application.

For the engine of your application, generic Symbian OS C++ will do. If you are a true beginner, my admittedly biased advice would be to procure a copy of [Quick Recipes on Symbian OS](http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com) since what you need to learn basically amounts to reading several chapters of that book. The code examples in the book will work on the w960i and will show you how to use the Symbian telephony and messaging APIs.